# Whether to use checkbox or radio button to distinguish an item

Tags: usability, forms

On my site, [CodeHive](https://www.codehive.io) we have a thing called Boards. Boards are used to either share a programming tip or ask a question. Currently we don't have a way to flag a Board to differentiate between a tip or a question. I'm trying to figure out what the best flow would be.

I was thinking either:

A. Make all Boards by default a question and add a checkbox at the bottom to indicate it is a tip, next to the submit button

or

B. Use 2 radio buttons that indicate either a tip or a question.

Or is there an even better UX element that could be introduced to enhance the overall flow?

Below is currently what I have for creating a new Board.

[image: Current: New Board UX]

Answer (score 2):

For me it would make sense to split the flow in two.  Have Add Tip and Ask Question flows.  This way there may be fewer mistakes when users are filling in the form.

Comment: Good, point. I was thinking about that as an option too. Seems to be a crude option but may be the most obvious. Thanks!

Comment: It would also allow you to be a bit more flexible if the flows differ later on.

Comment: Another option might be to work in a tab design which works alongside your "New Board" heading.

Comment: That's a good point, about the tab design. That way, additional elements could be swapped in and out based on whether it is a question or a tip.